# Unexpected results from worksheet function Countif

Tags: excel, vba

Have to remove all the duplicates in column C depending on certain range in column B.Column C has two consecutive rows and two or more blank cells before next value,the first value is text like document description and the row immediately below it has its respective number(generally( 6+ digits).Have to remove all duplicates depending on document description and document number. If the document description is the same but different  document number series like if first document  series is 654321delete all in 65xxxx series but retain anything other than 6xxxxx.
Have following lines of code which gets the range from column B and clears the content for only document description . But am not sure where have made a mistake. Wanted to to get started with document description and then add in code to check document number. But am unable to sort the first step out.This code is a block of the full code... 
Any assistance or a firm pushin the right direction would be much appreciated...

```
Do Until Range("B" & lngLastRow + 10).Value = "" 
  x = 2 
  y = x 

  Do 
    x = x + 1 
  Loop Until Range("B" & x).Value <> "" 

  For i = x To y Step -1 
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(y, "C"), Cells(i, "C")), Range("C" & i).Text) > 1 Then 
        Range("C" & i).Select 
        Selection.ClearContents 
    End If 
  Next i 

  y = y + x 
Loop
```

Comment: can you reformat your question? it's really long and hard to understand

Comment: Including a screen shot of your sheet would help greatly.

Comment: So if you have data like `Desp1,655361` and `Desp1,657896` and `Desp2,6567485` and `Desp1,642315` then what should happen?

Comment: If data series is like :Desp1,655361 and Desp1,657896 and Desp2,6567485 and Desp1,642315,then

Comment: `If data series is like :Desp1,655361 and Desp1,657896 and Desp2,6567485 and Desp1,642315,then –  Nandu 5 mins ago` Then What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading couple of times this is what I have understood from your question. Let's say your worksheet looks like this

[image]

Now you want to clear contents of the `Description` and the `Number` if the `Description` is duplicate and the number has the same series as to what series the first one started with.

If my understanding is correct then try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, ClearRng As Range
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim n As Long

    '~~> Change this to the releavnt worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Searching for this description. You can pick this
    '~~> Value from Col B
    SearchString = "Desp1"

    With ws
        '~~> Search Col C for the first match
        Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell
            '~~> Get the first two numbers to identify the series
            n = Left(aCell.Offset(1).Value, 2)

            '~~> Store the cells ina range
            Set ClearRng = Union(aCell, aCell.Offset(1))

            '~~> Find Next
            Do
                Set aCell = .Columns(3).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                    '~~> Check for series
                    If Left(aCell.Offset(1).Value, 2) = n Then
                        '~~> Store the cells ina range
                        Set ClearRng = Union(ClearRng, aCell, aCell.Offset(1))
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If

        '~~> I am coloring the range red. You can use ClearRng.Clearcontents
        If Not ClearRng Is Nothing Then ClearRng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End With
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Well, apologize for not properly framing the question . Column B consists of different department in a school and column C has the document description and respective document number.in case of data like  Desp1,655361 and Desp1,657896 and Desp2,6567485 and Desp1,642315,then col umn C must retain Desp1, 657896 and Desp2, 6567485. Largest document number must be retained.

Comment: `Largest document number must be retained` Fair enough. But why clear `Desp1,642315` That is from different series?

Comment: Usually there would be about0 to couple of thousands but less than 10000 of document numbers in the series .Need only  the highest number. And if the data is Desp1,655361 then its lower limit will be anywhere before Desp1,645362, if there exists Desp1,642315that will not be considered . Also if there be another Desp1, its number series will not be in 600000 but other than 600000. series.